# Slideshow: Last Image Flashing Length of Page?

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow, flexslider

A small portion of the last image on our flexslider is flashing the full length of the page immediately after the slideshow loads. The first image is set to visible and all other images are set to hidden. And the plugin is set to run after the page loads. I thought that perhaps something else on the page was causing this but if I disable every static block on the page except for the slider it still flashes. So I should therefore concluded it must be the slider? Here is an example of this in occurring on our staging site. Just keep hitting refresh to see it - http://www.shopcandelabra.com/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$j(window).load(function() {
   var loopCount = 0;
   $j("#carousel").flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      slideshowSpeed: 2000,
   start: function(slider){
        $('body').removeClass('loading');
    },
    after : function(slider){
       if(slider.currentSlide == 0 && loopCount == 1){
         slider.pause();
       }   
    },
    end : function(slider){
      loopCount++;  
      }
   });
});
</script>
```

```
.flexslider .slides>li:first-child {
    display: block;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;

.flexslider .slides>li {
    display: none;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flexslider .slides img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `float: left` to your `li` elements.

```
body.cms-home .main-container #candelabra-carousel.flexslider .slides>li {
  float: left;
}
```

**Causing:**

[image]

**After Fix:**

[image]

Comment: Fixed. Thank you!! Now I'm trying to stop the white flashing that's occurring after the flexslider images load. I've tried everything suggested here & elsewhere: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/848 - Any ideas?

Comment: @user9722 I'm not sure about this, but give this a try: `body.cms-home .main-container #candelabra-carousel.flexslider .slides>li.flex-active-slide { display: block; } `